# I want to force Word 2007 to paste text from any other source as red text keeping the format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Word 2007.
I have to create a complex document using text from various sources.
What I want to do is crate template that forces all text that is pasted into the document to be coloured red but retain all other formatting properties.
Then I will be able to quickly identify any pasted text which have not had my styles applied to them.
Is it possible to use VBA to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to catch all possible paste operations in your document and make the pasted cells text red colored. Since there are several possible ways to perform copy/paste in Excel this is not a trivial task. Here is a nice discussion to get you started:

[Catching Paste Operations](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp)